Kakao JS SDK Calls in Salesforce
I'm trying to develop a Salesforce component that makes a request to KAKAO API using the KAKAO JavaScript SDK.
this is my lwc Javascript code to initiate Kakao App

import {LightningElement} from 'lwc'
import {loadScript} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import kakaosdk from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/kakaoSDK';  // .js file in static Resource

export default class SdkTest1 extends LightningElement {
     jsKey = '******************';
     isInitialized = false;

     renderedCallback() {
         if(this.isInitialized){
             return;
         }
         this.isInitialized = true;
         loadScript(this,kakaosdk).then(()=>{
             console.log('### loading');
             const Kakao = window.KAKAO;  
             Kakao.init(this.jsKey);
             console.log(Kakao.isInitialized());

         })
             .catch((error)=>{
                 console.log('### error',error);

             })

     }

    connectedCallback() {

    }
}


i can't initiate my Kakao App and i can't get any error message..
How to use Kakao JS SDK in Lightning Web Components as 3rd party library? even can i use Kakao JS SDK in LWC?
initiate KAKAO in my salesforce , and use Kakao login api

The solution is to enable Lightning Web Security.

It's already checked to use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web Components and Aura components.
